# org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector is not a valid external type for schema of vector

Tags: java, apache-spark, vector, apache-spark-mllib

I have been working a lot with Big Data in Spark and I have a little blocker right now, I hope you can help me with this little issue.

I'm transforming a `Dataset<Row>` object into a `JavaRDD<Row>`, so in this way, I'm handling the transformation as:

```
//Dataset to RDDs
    JavaRDD<Row> trainingData = featureSelection.javaRDD().map(f -> {
        return RowFactory.create(Double.parseDouble(f.getString(4).trim()),
            Vectors.dense(Double.parseDouble(f.getString(0).trim()), Double.parseDouble(f.getString(1).trim()),
                Double.parseDouble(f.getString(2).trim()), Double.parseDouble(f.getString(3).trim())));
    });
```

So, then I need to define a `schema` to then transform again my data into a `Dataset<Row>` object.

My issue is when I'm creating the schema:

```
//Defining schema
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("features", new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT(), false, Metadata.empty())
    });
```

But, then I got this `stack trace`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector is not a valid external type for schema of vector
validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, label), DoubleType) AS label#111
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else newInstance(class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT).serialize AS features#112
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
```

So, it seems like I can't use `DenseVectors` to create the schema. I'm trying to find the correct `VectorStructure` to solve my problem but I'm not having luck. I have not tried yet with `Vectors.sparse` but if anyone has solved this problem, I really appreciate your help.

By the way, the spark version I'm using is `2.2.3`.

Thank you so much, to anyone!!

Comment: well, you mixed MLLib and Spark ML: `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` so you have to use `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector` and not `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` -

Comment: Thank you!! I have not seemed that wrong package.